# How to decrease a variable every second

Tags: arduino-uno

I am trying to count down the variable "bankValue" with a certain costfactor
The code I tried will perfectly count down the bankValue..but..

```
#define INTERVAL_MESSAGE1 1000

unsigned long time_1 = 0;

const float CostFactor = 1.0;
float bankValue = 10.00;
const float CostButton1 = 0.004167;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
    if(millis() >= time_1 + INTERVAL_MESSAGE1){
        bankValue = bankValue - (CostButton1 * CostFactor);
        time_1 +=INTERVAL_MESSAGE1;
        print_time(time_1);
        Serial.print("€");
        Serial.println(bankValue);
    }
   }
```

I want this the use in an if. 
IF button1 is pressed then bankValue will be decreased by a costfactor every second.

I tried this in an if

```
  if(Pushed == HIGH){
    if(Pushed != StatePushed){
    Serial.println("Button1 OFF");
    }

    digitalWrite(relayPin, LOW); 
  }else{
    if(Pushed != StatePushed){
    Serial.println("Button1 ON");
    }
                if(millis() >= time_1 + INTERVAL_MESSAGE1){
        bankValue = bankValue - (Button1Value * CostFactor);
        time_1 +=INTERVAL_MESSAGE1;
        print_time(time_1);
        Serial.print("€");
        Serial.println(bankValue);
        }
    digitalWrite(relayPin, HIGH);
     }
```

If the button is pressed, bankValue will decrease.
But when the button is not active....the millis timer keeps on running.
When switching on the button again, I see the bankValue decrease rapidly and not every second.

So the main question:
How can I decrease a variable every second when a button is active.

Comment: You are handling `millis()` wrong (should be `if(millis() - time_1 >= INTERVAL_MESSAGE1)` to avoid overflow issues), though that should not cause the seen behavior. Please show a full working sketch for the second code part

Comment: you may be attacking the problem from the wrong side ... you are checking the button state and then timing 1 second and decrementing the counter ... instead, you could continuously time 1 second intervals ... at each interval, check the button and act accordingly ..... you could also time 1/10 second intervals (ticks) and accumulate these when the button is pressed .... if 10 ticks have been counted, then decrement bankValue

Answer (score 1):

Your basic main problem is that you don't know when the button was pressed.  Your timing algorithm always works from the "last time the value was decremented" - and that could be hours ago.  When you press the button the difference between `millis()` and `time_1` could be massive, and it has to count up one second at a time until `time_1` passes `millis()`.

What you really need to do is separate out the button from the action. That makes it easier to manage.  You need to find the times when the button transitions from HIGH to LOW (pressed) and from LOW to HIGH (released). You're almost doing that right now, but not quite.  Then when you find the moment of being pressed you can say "From this moment forth you shall count."

For example you might change the first part of your code to be:

```cpp
if (Pushed != StatePushed) {
    StatePushed = Pushed; // Remember the current state for the next time round
    if (StatePushed == HIGH) { // Released
        Serial.println("Button1 OFF");
    } else { // Pressed
        Serial.println("Button1 ON");
        time_1 = millis(); // Remember what the time is right now
    }
}
```

That then is a single atomic operation and you can now at any time examine `StatePressed` to see if the button is pressed or not, and also at the moment of pressing `time_1` is set to the current `millis()` value, so you now know when the button was pressed.

Now you can add your second part using `StatePressed` as the trigger:

```cpp
if (StatePressed == LOW) { // Button pressed 
    if(millis() >= time_1 + INTERVAL_MESSAGE1){
        bankValue = bankValue - (Button1Value * CostFactor);
        time_1 +=INTERVAL_MESSAGE1;
        print_time(time_1);
        Serial.print("€");
        Serial.println(bankValue);
    }
}
```

However your method of comparing the time is not good. It doesn't handle the *millis rollover* problem.  Instead you should be using something more like:

```cpp
if (millis() - time_1 >= INTERVAL_MESSAGE1) {
    time_1 = millis();
    ... etc ...
}
```

Comment: tried your solution. Nearly worked :-)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use the solution post by Majenko and came up with something like this:

```
  if(Pushed != StatePushed) {
    if(Pushed == HIGH){
      if(Pushed != StatePushed){
        Serial.println("LED OFF");
        }
        digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);  // turn LED OFF 
        }else{
        if(Pushed != StatePushed){
        Serial.println("LED ON");
        time_1 = millis();
        }
        digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);  // turn LED OFF
        }     
  }       
         StatePushed = Pushed;

  delay(100);

  if(Pushed == LOW){
    if(millis() >= time_1 + INTERVAL_MESSAGE1){
      time_1 = millis();
        bankValue = bankValue - (coinValueB * CostFactor);
        time_1 +=INTERVAL_MESSAGE1;
        Serial.print("€");
        Serial.println(bankValue);
                Serial.println(INTERVAL_MESSAGE1);
    }
  }
```

Pretty much how you suggested it...
but I realize I absolutely do not understand how millis() exactly works.

I have no idea what this does:

```
if(millis() >= time_1 + INTERVAL_MESSAGE1)
```

In a way, the loop works. But the timing is really off.
With my settings, every second subtracting 0.004167, should be 0,25 is one minute.
But it was only around half...0,13 or so

Comment: It is off because you are adding INTERVAL_MESSAGE1 with time_1. Just remove that line. And don't use delay.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is in response to Niles's answer based on Majenko's answer (phew! that was a bit of a mouthful).

**millis()** returns how many milliseconds have passed since your program started.

And your timing is off because you are adding **INTERVAL_MESSAGE1** with **time_1** i.e. instead of waiting for one second you are actually subtracting after every two seconds. Hence, you got half the value you expected. Remove that line. (And also don't use delay).

I have isolated your substracting part of the code. Run this and you should see the result (button is connected to D4):

```
unsigned long PreviousTime = 0;
const unsigned long THRESHOLD = 1000;
const float CostFactor = 1.0;
float bankValue = 10.00;
const float CostButton1 = 0.004167;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(4, INPUT_PULLUP);
}



void loop() 
{
  if(digitalRead(4) == 0)
  {
    if((unsigned long)(millis() - PreviousTime) >=  THRESHOLD) // You need to check time like this to avoid overflow
    {
      PreviousTime = millis();
      bankValue = bankValue - (CostButton1 * CostFactor);
      Serial.println(bankValue);
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that `millis() - PreviousTime` is an `unsigned long`. No need to cast it.